# Create dummies on R including multiple categories

Tags: r, dummy-variable

I need to create a dummy which takes the value 1 if the original variable is equal to 3,4,5 and 0 otherwhise. the original variables is an index rescaled from 1 to 7. I already tried this code:

mediumcivlib<-(as.numeric(civlib==3,4,5)

but it gives me back a dummy with 1 corrisponding to three but not to four and five.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: You probably want something more like `civlib %in% c(3,4,5)`.

Comment: Sorry! I have something like: 

[ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 3 4 5 2 3 4 ]

and i want r to return me a variable with 1 for values 3,4,5 and 0 otherwhise:

[0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 ]

Answer (score 0):

The `%in%` operator checks whether each number in `civlib` can be found in the second vector of numbers - c(3, 4, 5) in this case. Wrapping this in `as.numeric()` converts the output from a logical (True or False) to a numeric output as you wanted.

```
civlib <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4)
as.numeric(civlib %in% c(3, 4, 5))
```